# I want to change the page content without reloading in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I am new to angular. i wanted to change the page content dynamically or may be show a new component with new content in it. i have cards on my website. please refer to the link
[Cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eapcw.jpg)

i want, to change the content of the page and show different content on each button clicked on card. i have already created a method and what to right in it.?

**Component.html**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onFirstClick()">Go somewhere</a>
```

**component.ts**

```
onFirstClick() {
}
```

Do i need to create a new component to show new content. what should i do? please help

Comment: You should create a new component and send content into it using @Input() decorator in angular

Comment: If you are new, I would suggest you to first try the ToH in the angular docs site

Answer (score 1):

Well depends on what you want to change dynamically, but Angular is really good in it anyhow. For example, if you want to switch the text of the button on the first click you could do:

component.ts:

```
buttonTxt: string = 'Click me';

onFirstClick() {
   this.buttonTxt = 'Button Clicked';
}
```

component.html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onFirstClick()">{{buttonTxt}}</a>
```

Changing dynamically what's on the page is the kind of thing angular is good and there are a bunch of different ways: ngIf*(Hide or show html component according to boolean variable on ts) and much more.

You can read a bit more about it here: https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-content-in-angular-2-3c85023d9c36